# Whats the difference between dequeue() and front() in Java Queue?

Tags: java, queue

I have two definitions from some college notes I'm reading.

"dequeue(): Remove the object from the front of the queue and return it; an error occurs if the queue is empty"

"front(): Return the front object in the queue, BUT DO NOT remove it; an error occurs if the queue is empty"

I understand the dequeue method but the front method has me a bit perplexed. Just wondering if someone has a good example of the front method being used so I can get my head around the difference between the two. Thanks.

Comment: It allows you to peek at it without committing.

Comment: The concept seems straightforward. If you want to know what's next without modifying your queue, use `front()`. 'Course, they could have not had that method, and required you to dequeue and then immediately queue if you wanted that behavior, but that takes a bit longer.

Comment: @PaulDraper, wouldn't that make it the last element then?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, depends on what you call the front vs. the back. In this case, you put elements on the back, and take them from the front. This is the same terminology as a line (queue) to the water fountain.

Comment: Seems like I was just overthinking it, thank you.

Comment: It's unclear what you don't understand about 'but DO NOT REMOVE'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a scenario with a single producer and multiple consumers. A particular thread-safe queue is used as the buffer between the different producers and consumers.

Now imagine that a particular consumer only has the ability to process a certain type of data from the queue. It could use the `front()` method to peek at the next data to see if it actually can process it and then call `dequeue()` if it can. If it cannot, it simply won't call `dequeue()`, leaving the queue unmodified.

Arguably, in the same scenario, you could call `dequeue()` to obtain the data, examine it, determine if you can process it. If not, add to the front of the queue again. But in this, it takes a lot more effort as the queue is being modified twice, and the action of putting an element back at the front of the queue may be expensive or completely prohibited. Most likely, you're adding the element to the end of the queue, disrupting the queue process order.

The `front()` method is a method to optimize queue access by keeping the number of modifications being done to the queue to a minimum given that queue modifications are usually more expensive than simple peeks at it. By looking at the first element without accessing it, consumers can decide if they are actually going to modify the queue, reducing the number of modifications when compared to `dequeue()` and the re-queuing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a Queue of `Integer`s that you are iterating over for whatever reason. You have a label on your UI that shows the upcoming number. To update that label, you will use `youeQueue.front()` to retrieve the number in question without removing it. When your next calculation starts, your calculation method will use `yourQueue.dequeu()` to retrieve the next element and remove it from the queue.